# Updating MDI child forms list after closing a form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

I am using DevExpress NavBar as main menu for my MDI application, and one of NavBar's groups contains items that represent opened MDI child forms. I am having trouble with updating a menu when a MDI child form closes.

I have to use **Form.MdiChildren** collection to generate menu group, but the problem is, when using **Form.FormClosing** event, that closed form is still in Form.MdiChildren collection. I tried to use a System.Timers.Timer to wait 1 second and then update a menu, but I get various exceptions because of asynchronous behavior (when a user closes few forms very fast).

I also cannot maintain my own list of MDI children, because of complexity of classes design.

Does anyone have some elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success with using this combination of methods:

```
private List<Form> _childForms = new List<Form>();

protected override void OnMdiChildActivate(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnMdiChildActivate(e);

   Form form = ActiveMdiChild;
   if (form == null)
       return;
   else
   {
       if (!_childForms.Contains(form))
       {
           _childForms.Add(form);
           form.FormClosed += mdiChildForm_FormClosed;
       }
   }
}

private void mdiChildForm_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   var form = (Form)sender;
   if (_childForms.Contains(form))
       _childForms.Remove(form);
   if (_childForms.Count > 0)
       _childForms[_childForms.Count - 1].Activate();
}
```

Note that the `Activate` method is called pretty much anytime the user interacts with a child form.  That includes opening and closing them.

You can then make use of the `childForms` collection to always know the open forms and do what you like with them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I really have to use Form.MdiChildren collection to keep track of open forms. This is the only object I can obtain all needed data of open forms. I have no control of opening  a form with Form.Show().

Comment: It would behoove you, then, to explain this requirement in some detail, because it is incredibly restrictive, and quite unusual.

Comment: Yes, after more exploring my code, I managed to adjust this approach. I just used event instead of protected method, because I cannot extend MDI Parent form. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*"I also cannot maintain my own list of MDI children, because of complexity of classes design."*

Is this because of the different class types?
What about holding a list of base classes?  like: `List<Form>` When there is a `FormClosed` event, just remove that form from the list.

Comment: Not because of that, its because when I call "launch form" I cannot get Text value of that form, to display in the menu. It is complex system that generates a menu based on user permissions, and some parts are in another dll which I cannot change.